# Android-Onfailedtoreceivead(ad request successful) occurs even in test mode?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have been trying to get ads running on my android app however they just wont appear. I searched numerous websites but none of them had the answer. Eventually I started using this tutorial http://www.smartlab.at/articles/admob_advertising_android_tutorial/. I downloaded the example and it worked perfectly so I copied the code. However ads don't show up for my app.

I know receiving a "onfailedtorecieve(ad request successful) due to lack of ad inventory"
error means that my code is fine, however the thing is that I am in test mode, and during my numerous hours of trying to figure how to add ads, I discovered that ads should always appear in testmode even if there is a lack of inventory. I entered my device id that I acquired from logcat and everything but still no ads appear. Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 


xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test"

android:id="@+id/main_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:debuggable="true"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

tools:context=".MainActivity" >  


      <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="AD UNIT ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
    />
```

I made sure to replace "TEST_DEVICE_ID" with my actual device id and the "AD UNIT ID" with the ad unit id I got from admob.

Here is my code in my activity:

```
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //hide title bar


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_view);





     adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adview); 
     adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

}

Like I said nothing shows up. However if I put my ad_unit_id in the example i downloaded from the tutorial website, it works perfectly.

Here is their code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a1501676c633fac" <!-- This is the adunitid in the tutorial i downloaded-->
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is their activity code:

```
package at.smartlab.androidbook.AdMobTest;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AdMobTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adview);


    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}
}
```

Interestingly, I don't have to put my actual device id in the xml code of the example I downloaded, it works fine whether I do put my id or I don't. Also, I can put either my adunitid or use theirs, it works fine either way.

I made sure to add the proper permissions in my androidmanifest.xml file and the proper  tags. Honestly, I don't see why ads don't show up on my app but do in the example I downloaded. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Docs mention removing loadAdOnCreate from the XML if you're looking the view up in code as you're doing.  https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android

Comment: Tried removing the loadAdOnCreate. Still no difference.

Answer (score 0):

First off you're using an old tutorial.

The tags should now be 
Com.Google.android.gms.adView.. Don't mind the random capital letters I'm on a mobile phone.  You also need to make sure you have an SDK for google play services

**XML**

```
   //at the top
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto 

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="your new pub Id goes here ca-app-something">

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**java**

```
       //calling ads
       adView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

       AdRequest adRequest=new.   AdRequest.Builder().build();
      adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**manifest**

```
   <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
    </activity>
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

**code to test the adview**

```
           adView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.MyAdView);
  AdRequest adRequest=new.AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").build();
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Also in your relative layout make sure you declare the package xlmns to com.google.android.gms.ads

Comment: Tried this a long time ago. Followed the correct google documentation and everything but it didn't work so I switched over to the old tutorial. I have the right SDK for google play services but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try it again and let me know what the logcat is showing. I just got ads to load for mine. Also make sure your package name in admob is correct

Comment: Logcat no longer says the onfailedtorecievead() part. Instead it says: 
No fill from ad server
failed to load ad: 3
also it says that 'The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.' However, Google Mobiles Ads SDK FAQ says I can ignore this.

Comment: Post your code. Also in your gen folder does it go com>google>android>gms and then all the adview stuff

Comment: I just started another project to test out if something was wrong with my project settings or something. I tried to put the admob code there. It works perfectly. For some reason the original project wouldn't display ads even though everything was fine. I can just display the ads on this new project and forget about the old one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like your package declaration in admob could of been misspelled